# Hadoop MapReduce mapper and reducer with multiple key types

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using MapReduce for building an inverted index for web search. I know how to use MapReduce with one key type, you set it here:

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ArrayListWritable.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(ArrayListWritable.class);
```

However, what if my keys can be of different types, is that supported? For example, one key may be just Text, another may be a PairOfWritables. I want to set different key types for output from the mapper to the reducer, and from the reducer to the final output. I have seen that there is a class called MultipleOutputs that allows specifying different keys and classes, but I'm unsure if this is the right situation to use it in. From the internet, it seems that a MultipleOutputs is only used in the reducer method, not the mapper.

Comment: I'm not a Hadoop expert, but it seems like this is a situation where you might expect to make multiple passes over the same data set, to get the different keys you need.  (Also, it seems like a situation where you might use a COTS search engine instead of building your own.  Have you looked at Lucene?)

Comment: @markspace wouldn't that be inefficient, to run through all the data multiple times? Also, I'm doing this for experimentation.

Comment: It's all basically O(n) though, and if the input data is immutable you can run the tasks in parallel.  Though as I said, I'm not an expert, and there might be better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea. How about you create a new class that can take any type of data that you are looking to pass onto the reduce. The class will contain a toString() method that ends up representing your data as a String. Using this string, use the Text class in Hadoop to be able to use that as a key